# Developing data entry application using angular material and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I wanted to build application using angular material design, `angularjs` (in `HTML`) and `javascript` which takes an input (name, place, phone-number & email) once submitted it has to be stored in table below it.

**Link to work in codepen 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QOoEyW**

I have tried various ways to materialize the code. Also the table should have solution of deleting the whole entry and editing the entered entry. I have tried a lot with code provided here. I was able to enter the data but unable to clear the data after submission

[image: Table entry & View]

```js
angular
  .module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.dataArray = [];
    $scope.add = function(data) {
      $scope.dataArray.push(data);
      $scope.data = null;
    }
    $scope.delete = function(index) {
      $scope.dataArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
  })
  .config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('docs-dark', 'default')
      .primaryPalette('yellow')
      .dark();
  });
```

```html
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" layout="column" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content md-theme="docs-dark" layout-gt-sm="row" layout-padding="">
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input ng-model="user.name" required="">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Place</label>
      <input ng-model="user.place" type="place" required="">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Email</label>
      <input ng-model="user.email" type="email" required="">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Phone</label>
      <input name="phoneNumber" ng-model="user.number" required="" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{10}$/" md-maxlength="10">
    </md-input-container>
  </md-content>
  <section layout="column" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center center" layout-wrap>
    <md-button ng-click="add(data)" class="md-raised md-primary">Click to Add</md-button>
  </section>
  <table>
    <th width="20%">Name</th>
    <th width="20%">Place</th>
    <th width="30%">E-mail</th>
    <th width="20%">Number</th>
    <th width="10%">Remove</th>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="entry in dataArray  track by $index">
      <td data-ng-bind="user.name"></td>
      <td data-ng-bind="user.place"></td>
      <td data-ng-bind="user.email"></td>
      <td data-ng-bind="user.number"></td>
      <td data-ng-click="delete(dataArray.indexOf(entry))"><a style="cursor:pointer;color:red">click</a></td>
    </tr>
    <table>
```

So please provide me with proper code..Else correct the provided code

Comment: You mean clearing the input fields? Why not just `$scope.user={}` ? Since the fields have `ng-model="user.name"`, `ng-model="user.place"` etc. it will clear them.

Comment: Hey Thanks..
I added it and checked it everything is cleared off in table ..Check the Image provided .Hope you understand my problem..Iff Can u please work the expected output and provide me with the code

Comment: Of course everything is cleared off the table. You have another error in your table, it should be `<td data-ng-bind="entry.name"></td>`. But since you bound it to `"user.name"`, then everything disappears when you clear `user`.

Comment: Hey Jeremy its not showing up in table after your suggestion.
I have provide the code pen link in post.Please review it and help me in getting required thing

Comment: Edited as suggested .Its not reflecting in table ..
after submission it should show up in table and prompt for next entry.
any corrections needed at javascript..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems with your code.

**First:**

```
<md-button ng-click="add(data)" class="md-raised md-primary">Click to Add</md-button>
```

Your function call is `add(data)` when it should be `add(user)`

**Second:**

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="entry in dataArray  track by $index">
```

You have `data-ng-repeat="entry in dataArray`, yet you use `user` to bind to the table. It should be `entry.name`, `entry.email`, etc.

Then, you can just add `$scope.user = {}` or `$scope.user = null` to your `$scope.add` function to clear the form fields.

Here's the fixed CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gXExoM

Comment: Hey Thanks @DGarvanski .. 
Also can you help me in editing the table in same application ?

Comment: @NawazKb ask a question, make sure it's a good question and then - maybe.